# Automatically respond to spécific subjects with mutt

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, smtp, mutt, gmail-imap

I need to automate some tasks.

Is there a way to receive a mail using *mutt* and respond to it if the subject match a desired list?

**Example**: If I receive a mail subject beginning with `hello` or `hi` or `welcome` then I want to send automatically a response mail with mutt if the mail subject match `hello` `hi` or `welcome`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way to do that with mutt.

Noted that you added the tag "microsoft-Outlook" as well, if using Outlook is acceptable for you, you can set up an inbox rule similar like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i use Manjaro distribution.

Comment: Okay... Then I am afraid there might be no way to achieve this.